# Reuse BootstrapVue component input when change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am new in VueJs and bootstrap vue.

When i use for example the input through my application 100 times and bootstrap-vue is going to change the component then i have to change this through my whole application.

Building my own input component with the bootstrap vue component is that a solution?

How can i achieve this?

```
<b-form-input v-model="text" placeholder="Enter your name"></b-form-input>
```

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean by "bootstrap-vue is going to change the component", please? You are afraid that functionality/syntax of b-form-input will change in some new version of bootstrap-vue?

Comment: @RadekSvítil if bootstrap change it's library component <b-form-input>. So if bootstrap-vue.org change this component

Comment: Well, if theoretically bootstrap-vue changes <b-form-input> component, you can safely use older version of bootstrap-vue with unchanged functionality.

Answer (score 0):

BootstrapVue has pretty much stabilized and one shouldn't see much change in the props (except for maybe expanded usage, or new props). Props that are deprecated or have deprecated syntax, will be noted in the documentation ahead of being removed.

Comment: I know, almost stable version. But if? is the question. If they change components

Comment: Change them how?

Comment: If bootstra-vue change a component

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much.